# Translate to Mongodb C# Driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Can someone please help me translate the following into code for the mongodb 2.4 C# driver? I have been trying to get this to work but I'm having a hard time figuring it out. When I run the following mongo query through the C# drive, I get no records. When I run through the mongo command line I get back 2 records.
I just need to understand what I am doing that is causing the difference in behavior when using the C# driver.

So far I have the following for the C# driver:

```
 public IEnumerable<ComponentRecordDataModel> GetComponentRecords(
        )
        {
            var componentTypeFilter = Builders<ComponentRecordDataModel>.Filter.Eq(x => x.ComponentType, "Investment");
            var authorizedUserFilter =
                Builders<ComponentRecordDataModel>.Filter.AnyEq(x => x.AuthorizedUserIds, "59e8c1d35e13de1494887658");

            var componentFieldFilters = new List<FieldValueDataModel>
            {
                new FieldValueDataModel()
                {
                    FieldId = "59d664d1c153f67518f98888",
                    Value = "gov"
                },
                new FieldValueDataModel()
                {
                    FieldId = "59d664d1c153f67518f98889",
                    Value = "azure"
                }
            };

            var componentFilters = new List<FilterDefinition<FieldValueDataModel>>();
            foreach (var componentFieldFilter in componentFieldFilters)
            {

                var bsonRegex = new BsonRegularExpression(Regex.Escape(componentFieldFilter.Value), "i");
                componentFilters.Add(Builders<FieldValueDataModel>.Filter.And(new[]
                {
                    Builders<FieldValueDataModel>.Filter.Eq(x => x.FieldId, componentFieldFilter.FieldId),
                    Builders<FieldValueDataModel>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Value, bsonRegex)
                }));
            }

            var fieldFilter = Builders<ComponentRecordDataModel>.Filter.ElemMatch(
                x => x.Fields, Builders<FieldValueDataModel>.Filter.Or(componentFilters)
                );

            var filter = componentTypeFilter & authorizedUserFilter & fieldFilter;
            var renderedFilter = filter.ToJson();

            return MongoContext.Find(filter).ToList();
        }
```

/*The mongodb query I am trying to replication is shown below*/

```
db.getCollection('componentRecords').aggregate(
    [{
            $match: {
                "componentType": "Investment"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "authorizedUserIds": {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        $in: ["59e8c1d35e13de1494887658"]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "fields": {
                    $elemMatch: { $or:
                     [{ $and : [
                                    { fieldId: ObjectId("59d664d1c153f67518f98888") },
                                    { value: { "$regex": "gov", '$options' : 'i' } }
                                    ]},
                                                           { $and : [
                                    { fieldId: ObjectId("59d664d1c153f67518f98889") },
                                    { value: { "$regex": "azure", '$options' : 'i' } }
                                    ]}                 
                                                                            ] 

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: What have you translated so far? Can you provide the snippets?

Comment: SO does not translate code from one language to another. Please show your effort and very nice people will feel honor to help you.

Comment: Can you please add couple of sample documents and poco's ? Can you confirm `fieldId`  is objectID and `authorizedUserIds` is string hex ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using linq ? it maybe easier to understand and write:

```
var arr = new [] { "59e8c1d35e13de1494887658" };
var id1 = ObjectId("59d664d1c153f67518f98888");
var gov = "gov";

var id2 = ObjectId("59d664d1c153f67518f98889");
var azure = "azure";

collection.AsQuerable().Where(w =>
w.componentType == "Investment" &&
w.authorizedUserIds.Any(a => arr.Contains(a.X)) &&
(
 (w.fieldId == id1 && w.value.ToLower() == go".ToLower()) ||
 (w.fieldId == id2 && w.value.ToLower() == azure.ToLower()) ||
)
).ToList();
```

Actually I didn't try this code in real example, but worked with linq in mongodb.

Comment: I thought about this but our team prefers to use FilterDefinition because we can serialize filter definition and compare with expected query that will be passed to the database.  We're also more comfortable using the native operators available through the driver as opposed to linq since we're not exactly sure what is happening under to hood with linq translation. Good suggestion and if all else fails I'll consider this solution.

Comment: You can serialize the whole query by using `ToJson()` at the end.  using linq will make life easier and will not lose performance, I think, coz from what I see it's not like linq to sql, the latter uses complex sql syntax to get what you want, but with mongo it's strict to specific number of methods and filters.